# How to write action for UIButton which is loaded into tableview as custom cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I'm new to iOS Development and i am using Objective C. I have a problem in UITableview.That is, i need to write action for multiple UIButton which is loaded into a tableview(DutiesTableView.m & .h) as a custom cell(BreakTimeCell.m &.h). That tableview(DutiesTableView.m & .h) is loaded into another tableview(ViewController.m&.h, TableName is PersonalTable) as s custom cell using XIB.
[Shift(custom cell),Duties(UITableview),Break Time(UITableview)],[This is my ViewController.m

[image: This is my breakTableview.m]

This is my sample output.When i click on the Break time UIButton it should show UIDatePicker on Main Tableview

[image: sample output]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code. Copy and paste your relevant code as text into your question. And please take time to format your question and use proper punctuation. The more effort you put into your question the better results you will get.

Comment: Sorry and Thank you @rmaddy

Comment: Still waiting for you to post your code as text instead of a picture.

Comment: Oops! i appreciate and thank you  for your responsibility.Mr.Shankar solved my problem.

Comment: @maddy tell me how to display same xib cell in next row if i click on the rounded plus button for both Duties(it's a XIB cell) and Break Time (it's XIB cell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegates to get call back from custom cell to your view controller, for example in the custom cell in your code, `BreakTimeCell.h` file declare a protocol and add button in  `BreakTimeCell.xib` and give outlet and action to custom cell like below,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class BreakTimeCell; //forword declaration 
@protocol BreakTimeCellDeleagte<NSObject>
- (void)breakTimeCell:(BreakTimeCell *)cell didTapTheButton:(UIButton *)aButton;
@end

@interface BreakTimeCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *aButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<BreakTimeCellDeleagte> cellDelegate;//this is important
- (IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender;
+ (BreakTimeCell *)getBreakTimeCell; //to get the custom cell
@end
```

and in `BreakTimeCell.h` file define action for the button

```
#import "BreakTimeCell.h"

@implementation BreakTimeCell

+ (BreakTimeCell *)getBreakTimeCell {
   NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BreakTimeCell" owner:self options:NULL];
   NSEnumerator *nibEnumerator = [nibContents objectEnumerator];
   BreakTimeCell *customCell = nil;
   NSObject* nibItem = nil;
   while ((nibItem = [nibEnumerator nextObject]) != nil) {
      if ([nibItem isKindOfClass:[BreakTimeCell class]]) {
         customCell = (BreakTimeCell *)nibItem;
         break;
     }
  }
  return customCell;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
   [super awakeFromNib];
   // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

   // Configure the view for the selected state
}

//call the delegate method in the button action 
- (IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender {
   if([self.cellDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(breakTimeCell:didTapTheButton:)])
    {
       [self.cellDelegate breakTimeCell:self didTapTheButton:sender];
    }
}
@end
```

and in view controller just set the cell delegate to view controller,

```
#import "ViewController.h" 
#import "BreakTimeCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, BreakTimeCellDeleagte>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }


 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
     return  1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return 10;
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   BreakTimeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MY_BREAK_CELL"];
   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [BreakTimeCell getBreakTimeCell]; //get the cell
   }
   cell.cellDelegate = self; //set the delegate to controller (self)
   return cell;
}

//this is the delegate method called for the button action.
- (void)breakTimeCell:(BreakTimeCell *)cell didTapTheButton:(UIButton *)aButton {
   NSIndexPath *indexPath =  [self.personalTable indexPathForCell:cell];
   NSLog(@"button tapped for index:%ld",(long)indexPath.row);
}
```

thats it, you will get output like below,

```
2017-12-13 11:44:24.693161+0530 Test[3082:100133] button tapped for index:3
2017-12-13 11:44:25.177169+0530 Test[3082:100133] button tapped for index:4
2017-12-13 11:44:26.223166+0530 Test[3082:100133] button tapped for index:0
2017-12-13 11:44:27.663060+0530 Test[3082:100133] button tapped for index:1
2017-12-13 11:44:28.495780+0530 Test[3082:100133] button tapped for index:2
```

Comment: Hi Mr. shankar in above picture there is rounded plus button if i click the button in next row the same xib cell should display how to do?

Comment: simple, put another button lets say, addNewTimeButton, and in its action call another delegate method to view controller, in view controller delegate method add another data to your array and reload the tableview

Comment: Hi Mr.shankar buddy i need a help. Can u give me sample code for sending request to server using NSURLSession in objective c language?.

Answer (score 1):

Create A button,

```
    UIButton *btnSample = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(215,10,100,50)];
    [btnSample setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [yourView addSubview:btnSample];
```

Add a action to button

```
    [btnSample addTarget:self action:@selector(your action or method) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Hello Hitesh, i uploaded my sample output, when i click on BreakTime Tableview button it should show UIDatePicker on Main Tableview not inside cell. so  how to do this?

Comment: @A.Yesuvin You can create a function and in that  present the UIVIewController with UIDatePicker as popover presentation

Answer (score 0):

Add this in cellForRow

```
   yourButton.tag = indexPath.row;
  [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(methodName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Perform task in below method

```
- (void)methodName:(id)sender
{
    // you can get index of button from sender.tag
}
```